# MySQL ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I am trying to write a mysql function which fetch data from different table & stores into the variables.. But I am getting the error as,
**ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function**

Please Please Help me.... My code is like below,

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION FUN_test(productId INT,quantity INT) RETURNS DOUBLE 
BEGIN
   DECLARE discountPer DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE unitPrice DOUBLE;
   DECLARE _discountId INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE _lowerLimit INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE _higherLimit INT DEFAULT 0;

   SELECT @unitPrice := `SellingUnitPrice` FROM `TBL_PRODUCT_MASTER` WHERE `Id` = productId;


SELECT @discountPer := discDetail.`DiscountPercentage`, @_discountId := disc.Id, @_lowerLimit := discDetail.LowerLimit, @_higherLimit = discDetail.HigherLimit FROM `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL` AS discDetail , `TBL_DISCOUNT` AS disc, TBL_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT AS prodDisc WHERE disc.`DiscountStartDate` < NOW() AND disc.`DiscountEndDate` > NOW() AND disc.`SchemeType` = 'AMOUNT' AND discDetail.DiscountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.productId = productId AND prodDisc.discountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.`IsEnabled` = 1 AND disc.`IsEnabled` = 1 AND (quantity * unitPrice) >= discDetail.LowerLimit and ((quantity * unitPrice) <= discDetail.HigherLimit);

  RETURN discountPer;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Use select ...into and @discountper is not the same variable as discountper.

Comment: After doing "select into " for all the variables... I am getting another error as ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: disc

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon for the response....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below sql.

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION FUN_test(productId INT,quantity INT) RETURNS DOUBLE 
BEGIN
   DECLARE discountPer DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE unitPrice DOUBLE;
   DECLARE _discountId INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE _lowerLimit INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE _higherLimit INT DEFAULT 0;

   SELECT `SellingUnitPrice` INTO @unitPrice FROM `TBL_PRODUCT_MASTER` WHERE `Id` = productId;

SELECT  discDetail.`DiscountPercentage` , disc.Id INTO @discountPer, @_discountId FROM `TBL_DISCOUNT_DETAIL` AS discDetail , `TBL_DISCOUNT` AS disc, TBL_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT AS prodDisc WHERE disc.`DiscountStartDate` < NOW() AND disc.`DiscountEndDate` > NOW() AND disc.`SchemeType` = 'AMOUNT' AND discDetail.DiscountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.productId = productId AND prodDisc.discountId = disc.Id AND prodDisc.`IsEnabled` = 1 AND disc.`IsEnabled` = 1 AND (quantity * unitPrice) >= discDetail.LowerLimit and ((quantity * unitPrice) <= discDetail.HigherLimit);


  RETURN discountPer;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: This shouldn't be selecting into `@discountPer`, it should select into `discountPer`.  Those are two different variables.  And _discountId is doing nothing.